# split out object property and values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

From this json arrays

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "John",
            "type": "B",
            "score":"passed"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Alice",
            "type": "A",
            "score":"failed"
        }

    ]
}
```

How to split out some field and turn it intosomething like this

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "B",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "A",
        }

    ]
}
```

I do not want to use splice in my case, above is just sample code.

Comment: The string you posted is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Pointy updated my question, i do not want to delete, above code is just sample code.

Comment: @thefourtheye sorry updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean, "just sample code"? If you can't pose a clear question how do you expect to get help?  The only difference between the (inexplicably edited) lists above is that the objects in the second one are missing two attributes present in the first one.

Comment: @Pointy just don't use delete because I need only few field, delete is bad in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var input = {
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "John",
            "type": "B",
            "score":"passed"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Alice",
            "type": "A",
            "score":"failed"
        }

    ]
};
var output = {
    result: input.result.map(function(item) {
       return {
          id: item.id,
          type: item.type
       };
    })
}
```

Comment: you don't need `""` for result?

Comment: @JamesLemon no, you don't need quotes for keys.

Comment: what if I just want array? discard the result key?

Comment: @JamesLemon then just use `var output = input.result.map(function(item) { ... });`

Comment: u will get an error, unexpected token .

Comment: @JamesLemon where I'll get an error?

Comment: if u don't use a key, line input.result.map(function(item) {

Comment: @JamesLemon if you don't use key then you can't use object it will work, check my comment.

Comment: my bad, my mistake, ur code should work

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```js
   var json = {
   "result": [{
           "id": "1",
           "name": "John",
           "type": "B",
           "score": "passed"
       }, {
           "id": "2",
           "name": "Alice",
           "type": "A",
           "score": "failed"
       }

   ]
   };

   json.result.forEach(function(item) {
   delete item.name;
   delete item.score;
   });

   console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 3):

iterate over arry and remove age property

```
var json = [
    {"name":"john",
     "age":"30",
     "gender":"male"},
    {"name":"Alice",
     "age":"20",
     "gender":"female"}

];
json.forEach(function(x){
delete x['age'];
})
```

Comment: simple yet working solution, just nice.